# How do I count values grouping by month and year (YYYYMM) in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, analysis

Example:

```
year_month = ['201801','201801','201801','201801','201801','201802','201802','201802','201802','201802']
Services = ['23','67','23','67','23','23','23','4','4','67']
df = list(zip(year_month, Services)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Date', 'Services'])
```

Help me!

My date column is already in the right format, and I`ve alread have the YYYTMM column from that.

I tried something like:
df2 = df.loc[:, ['YYYYMM', 'Services']]
df2 = df.groupby(['YYYYMM']).count().reset_index()

EXPECTED OUTPUT
Quantity of services per month/year.

year_month  4  23  67

201801      0   3   2

201801      2   2   1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD5i5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
out = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).count()
```

`out`

```
    Date    Services
0   201801  5
1   201802  5
```

---

**Update**

finally i know desired output.

```
pd.crosstab(df['Date'], df['Services']).sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.astype('int'))
```

```
Services    4   23  67
Date            
201801      0   3   2
201802      2   2   1
```

Comment: Hi, tks for answering. but I want to know quantity for each service.

Comment: then make your desired output by text or image

Comment: Ok! I put a expected output in a picture at the description.

year_month 4 23 67

201801 0 3 2

201801 2 2 1

Comment: twice 20180101?

Comment: sorry, 20180102 in the second line

Comment: uhuul! Tks very much!

Comment: @rank i update my answer.  Your example code(`df`) is also wrong.  plz check your code before asking and provide desired output , then you will  get code you want.

Comment: I'm new on that. Tks for the tip

Comment: @rank I am 46 days newbie. Don't think me spicy. I just can't English well, so there may be misunderstandings.
Anyway grats for solving your problem